# Removing scanner selection from Windows' scan window

Tags: windows, scanner, adobe-photoshop, windows-vista

I'm having an issue with scanner services showing up. I recently reinstalled Photoshop, but it seems that the old "scanner service" stayed.

Assistance in removing this will be appreciated.

Screenshot:

[image: The scanner prompt]